# Developer tools editing stopped working

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Has anyone ever had Chrome/Safari dev tools refuse to edit styles? I change values and on enter they go back to their original values. I have used the w3c css validator and everything looks fine. Any ideas or experience would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried quiting and restarting the browser?

Comment: Yes, it definitely the site, even locally and on several computers.

Comment: This is a bug. Please file a it on [crbug.com](http://crbug.com) with repro steps.